# ASP.NET LINQ query using "into" keyword to produce result bundled as sequence

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the NFL season schedule saved in an SQL Server DB. A `Game` table has fields of `Week` (referring to the week of the season in which the game takes place [1-17]), `AwayTeamID`, and `HomeTeamID`, among others. The `AwayTeamID` and `HomeTeamID` fields are foreign keys referencing the `Team` table. I want to use a LINQ statement (within an ASP.NET MVC 3 app) to return games by week, including team names from the `Team` table. I know at least one way to do this, but specifically (and I'm hoping more elegantly), I'd like return a result that has each week associated with a sequence of games that correspond to that week, instead of a returning a sequence of `new { Game, AwayTeam, HomeTeam }` objects and then drilling into the `Game` item to get the week. I'm not sure I've made my goal clear...if not, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

I read on [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9) about something similar using the `into` keyword within a `join` statement so that the result would be a sequence of weeks, each associated with its own sequence of games. Using the example from that site, I tried the following:

```
    string[] wks = { "1", "2", "3" };

    var model =
        from g in _db.NFLGames
        join a in _db.NFLTeams on g.AwayTeamID equals a.NFLTeamID
        join h in _db.NFLTeams on g.HomeTeamID equals h.NFLTeamID
        select new TestGameModel { Game = g, AwayTeam = a.Name, HomeTeam = h.Name };

    var weekgames = 
        from w in wks
        join gm in model on w equals gm.Game.NFLWeek into gw
        select new TestNflWeeklySchedule { Week = w, Games = gw };

    foreach (var wg in weekgames) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NFL week: " + wg.Week + "     number of games this week: " + wg.Games.Count());
        foreach (var g in wg.Games) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  " + g.AwayTeam + " at " + g.HomeTeam + " [" + g.Game.DateTimeStart + "]");
        }
    }
```

The code executes, but the output is

```
NFL week: 1     number of games this week: 0
NFL week: 2     number of games this week: 0
NFL week: 3     number of games this week: 0
```

Apparently, the second query joining the `model` is not matching the games that occur in the designated week. I've also tried, instead of two queries, just one LINQ statement, which essentially nests the first query within the second. That gave me the same result.

Can anyone tell me what error I have in my code or why this is not working? I'm new to LINQ, so there's a good chance it's something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var weekGames = _db.NFLGames.GroupBy(g => g.NFLWeek);

foreach (var wg in weekGames)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Week: " + wg.Key + " Games: " + wg.Count());

    foreach (var g in wg) 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(g.AwayTeam + " at " + g.HomeTeam + " [" + g.Game.DateTimeStart + "]");
    }
}
```

Comment: That gets me half way. But what code would I need to include to return the names of teams (instead of IDs) in the result. The line showing g.AwayTeam would need to be changed to g.AwayTeamID, because an NFLGame object only has a foreign key ID reference, not the actual string value of the team name. Any ideas?

Comment: You can add your joins before the .GroupBy

Comment: I tried something like that (albeit using the comprehension syntax instead of the extension method syntax) previously, but wasn't sure how to write the select statement...what would the object in the select line look like?

Comment: Something like: `_db.NFLGames.Join(_db.NFLTeams, g => g.AwayTeamID, t => t.NFLTeamID, (g, t), new { Week = g.NFLWeek, GameID = g.NFLGameID, AwayTeam = t, HomeTeamID = g.HomeTeamID}).Join(_db.NFLTeams, g => g.HomeTeamID, t => t.NFLTeamID, (g, t), new { Week = g.Week, GameID = g.GameID, AwayTeam = g.AwayTeam, HomeTeam = t}).GroupBy(g => g.Week);`. That's off the top of my head, so some parameters may be mixed up!

Comment: I was playing around with it and got it to work using the other syntax. So I got the result I needed. I'll take a look at this too as a reference. Thanks for the help. If anyone else is looking at this, though, I'd still be interested in knowing how to do the same with the "into" keyword in a join statement (if it's possible, which I'm thinking it is). Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure! When it comes to joins, the query expression syntax is much friendlier than the fluent equivalent.